# For loop fetching all values except one value

Tags: selenium

I am trying to fetch all the values with the help of for loop except one value its printing other all 541 values. This code  `//div[3]/table/tbody/tr[*]/td[contains(text(), '' )][3]` giving me **542 elements(td)** And particularly the value of **td no-10** is not getting displayed **i.e. 106/188**.

```
td style="width: 100px; color: #333; font-size: 14px; text-align:center;" xpath="11">0/7 /td  
td style="width: 100px; color: #333; font-size: 14px; text-align:center;" xpath="12">**106/188** /td
td style="width: 100px; color: #333; font-size: 14px; text-align:center;" xpath="13">265/768 /td  
td style="width: 100px; color: #333; font-size: 14px; text-align:center;" xpath="14">1024/4567 /td  
td style="width: 100px; color: #333; font-size: 14px; text-align:center;" xpath="15">3/38   /td
```

My following code is printing all 541 values and all are correct.

```
 for(int av=va+12; av<listOfActualValues.size(); av++)

             { 
                System.out.format("%25s",listOfActualValues.get(av).getText());
                actValue = listOfActualValues.get(av).getText();

                String str1 = listOfActualValues.get(av).getText().split("/")[1];
                String str2 = listOfActualValues.get(av).getText().split("/")[0];
                      value1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
                      value2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);
                // actValue = listOfActualValues.get(av).getText();
                   break;
             }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your XPath references divs, table, and a td[3]. But your HTML is just a few `td` elements and that's it. It's hard to tell what is going on here without a complete picture of the page HTML. Sounds like your for loop might just be off by one.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to change xpath value, its different for all td's. You can see edited code.

Comment: Can you comment what is going on in for loop? Why does it break after first iteration? Why `av=va+12`?